# Field extensions and unions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

If $F$ is a subfield of a field $E$ and if $S = S_1 \cup S_2$, the $F(S) = F(S_1)(S_2)$.

I understand why this has to be so, but I can't seem to prove it rigorously.

Could someone help?

Comment: This depends on your definitions. What is your definition of $F(S)$?

Comment: @AlexMathers it's the smallest subfield of $E$ that contains both $F$ and $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice $S_1\subseteq F(S_1)(S_2)$ and $S_2\subseteq F(S_1)(S_2)$, so $S\subseteq F(S_1)(S_2)$; of course also $F\subseteq F(S_1)(S_2)$ so since $F(S)$ is the smallest subfield of $E$ containing $F$ and $S$ we deduce $F(S)\subseteq F(S_1)(S_2)$.

The reverse inclusion is similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What happens if I define $F(S)$ as the intersection of all fields $L$ that satisfy $F \subset L \subset E$ and $S \subset L$? ("$\subset$ denotes a subfield). In exercises we've always used $F(S)$ with the definition as in the comments above, but this is what our professor actually defined it as. I'm assuming it gives the same answer but I just wanted to check!

Comment: @SamoGrecco it is straightforward to prove that this second definition is equivalent to the first definition, so I would just do that first!